# What information does Facebook connect actually give a developer

Tags: facebook

Having read the Facebook connect documentation I'm unable to determine what information I will have.

I realise I will have the Profile photo & Proxy email and access to a friends mechanism. I'm reasonably sure I will have access to First name and surname. Will I have access to things like Age?

EDIT: This isn't a Facebook APP, I'm using Facebook connect. RE: bobcat's response, can you still use Users.getInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a facebook user has okayed your app, you can use the API including [`Users.getInfo`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo) which gives you the users birthday.

**update** As far as I can tell from the docs, when a user uses facebook connect to authenticate on a website, then the website can do anything that a facebook app could, with a few restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this post still came up when searching for something similar with Facebook login information, despite how old the post is.

Facebook is now using the term "FB.login" which was known as "Login with Facebook". It provides you with information that you request, whether that be an email and birthday, to profile information of their name and address, etc.

I found this link that will tell you the permissions you can request using FB.login here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

There are plenty of options for requesting information and posting on their behalf.

I was searching for the access token information to keep the connection while registering or signing in. That information I found at the bottom of the next section of their documentation, found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/